# AngularJS Chart file issues

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm relatively new to angular, and tried customizing an angular charts template. However after saving the files and attempting to open the html, nothing appears in the browser. At first I thought this may have been due to typos or errors in my source code, but I haven't found what I did wrong. Where is the error in my code?

My markup:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Angular Chart</title>
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.11/d3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/bower/dist/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div 
        data-ac-chart="'line'" 
        data-ac-data="data" 
        data-ac-config="config" 
        class="chart">
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

My JS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularCharts']);

    function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.config = {
    title: 'Products',
    tooltips: true,
    labels: false,
    mouseover: function() {},
    mouseout: function() {},
    click: function() {},
    legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'right'
   }
  };

   $scope.data = {
     series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
     data: [{
       x: "Laptops",
       y: [100, 500, 0]
     }, {
       x: "Desktops",
       y: [300, 100, 100]
     }, {
       x: "Mobiles",
       y: [351]
     }, {
       x: "Tablets",
       y: [54, 0, 879]
     }]
    };
   }
```

Comment: Bring up the developer tools (press F12 on your browser) and look at the Console tab. Angular usually provides excellent error descriptions.

Comment: I checked out the console errors and it gave me this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined` . It says the error is on line 3 where I included $scope in the controller dependencies. What does this mean? That seems to be the root error. Also, this was after I altered my controller code based on your feedback. The other error it shows is `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: The first problem is that you were accessing $scope.data outside any function. $scope is a value passed in as a parameter to a controller function - it is not a global object. As to the [ng:areq] problem, I don't know. Could you try updating your angular version from 1.2.2 to 1.4.2?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I forgot to put ticks around `$scope` and it fixed the errors. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your controller with the Angular module.

Something like this:

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularCharts']);

  myApp.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.config = {
          title: 'Products',
          tooltips: true,
          labels: false,
          mouseover: function () {},
          mouseout: function () {},
          click: function () {},
          legend: {
              display: true,
              position: 'right'
          }
      };

      $scope.data = {
          series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
          data: [{
              x: "Laptops",
              y: [100, 500, 0]
          }, {
              x: "Desktops",
              y: [300, 100, 100]
          }, {
              x: "Mobiles",
              y: [351]
          }, {
              x: "Tablets",
              y: [54, 0, 879]
          }]
      };
  }]);
```